# How can I simulate my site?

Tags: emulation

I have a website that doesn't work in IE8, due to [a ton of issues](http://bigassmessage.com/abaec).

Apparently, some people don't understand. There is no way my site will ever work natively in IE8.

## MY GAME WILL NEVER WORK NATIVELY IN IE VERSION EIGHT.

As a workaround, I want to place a Java applet on it that simulates a browser. This way, people - 25.8% of people - can see my site in IE8 by viewing the site through the applet.

Basically, it would work something like the emulator at http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mini/ - except not Opera Mini.

Thus: Are there any emulators that I can put on my site that emulate other browsers? They could be JS/HTML5, Java, Flash, whatever.

{Opera Mini doesn't work with my site - so unfortunately this otherwise perfect example from Opera doesn't work, but any of the current versions of the Big 5 (IE, Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari) would work with my site flawlessly.}

Comment: What? Don't do that... it's just a bad idea. If you're running on Windows, all versions of IE have IE 8 mode in the F12 Developer Tools. Otherwise, try something like [Browserling](http://browserling.com/) or one of the several alternatives.

Comment: What kind of issues are causing the site to fail completely in IE8? It's better to find a way to get your site to work in IE8 (if it's compatible with IE8, it'll most likely also work in IE7, and there are plenty of users out there still loading that dinosaur). I find it to be just as problematic getting IE9 to load sites properly as conforming to IE8's requirements. Eliminating the errors is always a better approach than hiding them. If you're going the route of simulating, you might as well show a modal window with a link to download Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Or you could something like VirtualBox and/or XPMode to keep multiple installs of various versions of IE and other browsers around.

Comment: @minitech: What would be one of these several alternatives? Yes, I know that it's generally considered good practice. No, there is no way that I am going to port 10,000 lines of Javascript to IE8's freakishly limited supposed 'javascript'. Right now, I have an alert() that tells them their browser is really old and they need to upgrade **now**. A vast majority of these users wouldn't know what a browser was if it jumped off the screen and hit them in the face. Thus, what do I do? An emulator.

Comment: @Lazerblade: I tried to go through them and make a list, and it's so long that I wouldn't have any hope of doing this. IE9 and all other modern browsers play my game flawlessly. IE8 throws about as many JS errors as my game has lines of code.

Comment: Oh... I thought you were trying to... never mind. Okay, what features do you use that don't work on IE8? You'd be surprised at how good shivs are for fixing everything.

Comment: @JavaAndCSharp Understood. An emulator might be a good option for you then. If you can find one. An alternative, however, might be to convert your javascript to jQuery, which handles translating the code based on the browser for you. 10k lines of code is a lot to convert, but again, with jQuery you may find more compatibility for older browsers, including IE8 and 7, plus the added advantage of a more streamlined ability to update the code in the future.

Comment: @minitech: ...you know, when I first read that comment, it seemed like you were suggesting I stab my IE8 users with a shiv. BTW, which shiv would you recommend? It could go a bit toward fixing some of the issues. maybe the one at https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv?

Comment: @JavaAndCSharp: Yup, that one looks good. I usually use another shiv (trying to find it now) but that one seems fine.

Comment: The link to "a ton of issues" could cause epileptic seizures. Please remove it or tone it down.